# Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference in jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery

i am using arborjs0.92 version.when i run ie10 it show on Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference in jquery.min.js. how can i solve this issue.

Comment: look at the error trace in your browser console to see which of your code triggered the error

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1bjsv6k8/2/ - if you open the dev console(Chrome) and expand the error message you will see the trace message from `index`(line 24) that is the line causing the problem

Comment: Please provide fiddle @s Vivekanandan

Comment: @Arun P Johny, you have an error in fiddle because you are looping through variable which is not initialized. Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1bjsv6k8/3/) Fiddle. You will not get error because i have initialized variable to type Array

Comment: @Innodel yes I know... I was just telling OP how to find out which of the OPs line was causing the error

Comment: https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/issues

Comment: Someone edited a question 2014 that should have been closed in 2014. lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statement. If object is null then length is 0 otherwise get the length by using length property of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Before using .length property, check whether the variable is null/undefined/or some other falsy value. If Yes then assign length 0 else calculate the length. Eg :

```
var reference,   // ref is undefined
    refLength; 

if(reference) {
    refLength = reference.length;
}
else {
    refLength = 0;
}
```